# Syntax - document.write Javascript into html

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to figure out how to pass some PHP variables into Javascript so they can be called by the html.  Here is the orginal markup from jplayer.org that I'm trying to work with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function (event) {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                title: "Bubble",
                m4a: "http://jplayer.org/audio/m4a/Miaow-07-Bubble.m4a"
            });
        },
        swfPath: "../../dist/jplayer",
        supplied: "mp3",
        wmode: "window",
        useStateClassSkin: true,
        autoBlur: false,
        smoothPlayBar: true,
        keyEnabled: true,
        remainingDuration: true,
        toggleDuration: true
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
```

So, I'm trying to make the "title" and "m4a" dynamic as variables.  I tried this:

```
<script>
    var audio_file = '<?php echo $full_audio; ?>'; 
    var audio_title = '<?php echo $title; ?>';
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function (event) {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                title: document.write(audio_title);,
                m4a: document.write(audio_file);
            });
        },
        swfPath: "../../dist/jplayer",
        supplied: "mp3",
        wmode: "window",
        useStateClassSkin: true,
        autoBlur: false,
        smoothPlayBar: true,
        keyEnabled: true,
        remainingDuration: true,
        toggleDuration: true
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
```

But when I inspect the html, instead of the variable being added, I get the actual text

```
"title: document.write(audio_title);,
m4a: document.write(audio_file);"
```

I'm not overly proficient with Javascript, any advice?

Comment: could this help? values echoed from php are wrapped in single quotes. `var audio_file = '<?php echo $full_audio; ?>'; var audio_title = '<?php echo $title; ?>';`

Comment: 1. `var audio_file = "<?php echo $full_audio; ?>"; ` - assuming `$full_audio` is a string you need to wrap it in quotes to make valid JS. 2. then you have syntax errors in the object after `setMedia`.

Comment: Ok, I wrapped in quotes as recommended, and tested.  The variables are set, I can see those, but I'm not getting the document.write() as expected.

Comment: Instead of 'document.write(audio_file);', you can simple use 'audio_file' since its declared as a javascript global variable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why you're using `document.write( )` to set those config variables in `jPlayer( )`.  Have you tried just calling the Javascript variables there instead?  Also make sure that your two variables are being set to the correct values where you're calling the PHP.

Try this:

```
<script>
    var audio_file = '<?php echo $full_audio; ?>'; 
    var audio_title = '<?php echo $title; ?>';
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function (event) {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                title: audio_title,
                m4a: audio_file
            });
        },
        swfPath: "../../dist/jplayer",
        supplied: "mp3",
        wmode: "window",
        useStateClassSkin: true,
        autoBlur: false,
        smoothPlayBar: true,
        keyEnabled: true,
        remainingDuration: true,
        toggleDuration: true
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
```

Just to clarify, you'll only see the values of `$audio_file` and `$audio_title` where you set them.  Within `jPlayer( )` you'll only see the variable names but that's the way it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function (event) {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            title: audio_title,
            m4a: audio_file
        });
    },
    swfPath: "../../dist/jplayer",
    supplied: "mp3",
    wmode: "window",
    useStateClassSkin: true,
    autoBlur: false,
    smoothPlayBar: true,
    keyEnabled: true,
    remainingDuration: true,
    toggleDuration: true
});
});
//]]>
</script>
```

I have just removed the document.write from line 4 & 5 below '$(document).ready(function(){' as document.write writes the variables to the page instead of assigning it to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language and javascript is client side. You have to store that php value in any hidden input type. And then u can access it.